# Undo operation using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to implement undo and redo operation for my paint application.

I created class which extends from jpanel and here i have arraylist to keep all the elements on my jpanel.

This how it works when i add new element (f.e i draw something with pencil tool):

```
this.elements.add(new PencilElement(this.tool.getPPoint(), this.tool.getCPoint(), this.tool.getColor(), this.tool.getStroke()));
```

I want to use another arraylist to keep copy of all elements and when i click "undo" button:
-->last element from temporary array list would be removed 
-->content of base arraylist (in this case "elements" arraylist) would be replaced by this temporary arraylist content.

If you have another ideas, please share

Thanks!

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: the classical pattern for undo - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stack using Deque ([Why should I use Deque over Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack))

A suggestion is to use a stack for the actions also, so you simply can pop from the ordinary action stack and push on the undo stack, and the other way around when making a redo.

//suggestion for current solution

```
private Deque<PencilElement> undoStack = new ArrayDeque<PencilElement>();

//whenUndo
undoStack.addFirst(myPencilElement);

//whenRedo
elements.add(undoStack.removeFirst());


//New suggestion
//whenUndo
undoStack.addFirst(elements.removeFirst());

//whenRedo
elements.add(undoStack.removeFirst());
```

also make sure to disable redo when no actions on the stack

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make a redo, then you should not delete the last element from the second ArrayList, because you will need it for the redo.