# Java Postfix char to String conversion

Tags: java, junit, bluej

Using BlueJ to write the code and jUnit to test it out.

Trying to convert a infixToPostfix class I have from my lab class from using char to using strings. This would make it so instead of being limited to single input of say "ab+c-d*-" of char's, it would be able to read "a b + c - d * -"

It's working with a stack which is fairly new to me and I have no idea how exactly I'd go about this. The code I have so far is:

```
public class InfixToPostfix
{
private Stack operators = new Stack();

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class InfixToPostfix
 */
public InfixToPostfix()
{

}

/**
 * toPostfix
 */
public String toPostfix(String infix)
{
    String [] tokens = new String[100];
    int i;
    int length = infix.length();
    String operator;
    String output = "";

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (isOperator(tokens[i]))
            if (operators.empty())
                // 2. If the stack is empty, push the incoming operator onto the stack.
                operators.push(tokens[i] + " ");
            else
            {
                if (operatorLessPrecedence(tokens[i]))
                // 3. If the incoming symbol has equal or lower precedence than the
                //    symbol on the top of the stack, pop the stack and print the top
                //    operator. Then test the incoming operator against the new top of stack.
                //    Push the incoming symbol onto the stack.
                {
                    do
                    {
                        output = output + operators.pop();
                    }
                    while (!operators.empty() && operatorLessPrecedence(tokens[i]));
                    operators.push(tokens[i] + " ");
                }
                else
                    // 4. If the incoming symbol has higher precedence than the top of the stack,
                    //    push it on the stack.
                    operators.push(tokens[i]);
            }
        else
            // 1. Print operands as they arrive.
            output = output + tokens[i] + " ";
    }
    while (!operators.empty())
    {
        // 5. At the end of the expression, pop and print all operators on the stack.
        operator = (String)operators.pop();
        output = output + operator + " ";
    }
    return output;
}

/**
 * isOperator
 */
public boolean isOperator(String c)
{
    if(  c.equals("/") ||
         c.equals("'") ||
         c.equals("+") ||
         c.equals("-"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * operatorLessPrecedence
 * Compare operator with top of stack
 * Assume association left to right
 */
public boolean operatorLessPrecedence(String o)
{
    int operatorPrecedence = precedence(o);
    int tosPrecedence = precedence((String)operators.peek());
    return (operatorPrecedence <= tosPrecedence);
}

/**
 * precedence
 */
public int precedence(String o)
{
    switch (o)
    {
        case "+": return 1;
        case "-": return 1;
        case "*": return 2;
        case "/": return 2;
    }
    return 5;
}
```

}

So when I test in jUnit using a assertEquals;

```
@Test
public void testAddSub()
{
    InfixToPostfix test = new InfixToPostfix();
    assertEquals("1 2 +", test.toPostfix("1 + 2"));
    assertEquals("2 1 -", test.toPostfix("2 - 1"));
}
```

I get an exception method currently, before i changed the isOperator method from "==" which was used for testing char's to what I thought was correct, the .equals() method to test strings, I would only get null outputs..

I don't want a straight up code or what exactly I'm doing wrong, just a "forceful" nudge in the right direction or something I can look into. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of objects holds a *reference* to the object. When you initialized the array, you just allocated the memory for 100 empty spots. You have to put some real Strings objects on it, otherwise `NullPointerException` 'll be your output.

So, in your line

> String [] tokens = new String[100];

You have an array of 100 Strings *references* which values are **null**.

---

The correct way to compare `String` objects is using `equals` method.

Using `==` you'll test object *references*, `equals` tests the `String` value. So, don't change your method implementation, you are in the right path.

---

I don't recommend the use of Stack object. As you stated that Stack is a new thing for you and you are trying to improve, I would recommend that you take a look at this discussion if you have time available and get your own conclusion.
[Why should I use Deque over Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack).