# Stack<Obj> stack = otherStack creates a pointer to otherStack?

Tags: java, stack

I am currently working on an object-structure exercise where I implement a simple Twitter-interface. I have a TwitterAccount object and a Tweet object. The TwitterAccount object has a Stack that contains all the tweets. In my getTweet(index)-method, I want the newest tweet to be returned with getTweet(1), and second-newest with getTweet(2)... etc.

I do this by creating a temporary tweet-stack, pop index-1 Tweets off the temporary stack, then return the next one. My issue is that the original tweets stack also has it's elements popped. Did I create a pointer to the tweets stack when I created the temporary stack?

```
Stack<Tweets> tweets;

(...)

public Tweet getTweet(int index) {

    Stack<Tweet> tempTweets = tweets;
    for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) 
        tempTweets.pop();

    return tempTweets.pop();

}
```

Comment: "*Did I create a pointer to the tweets stack when I created the temporary stack?*" ==> yes.

Comment: Unless you are not creating a new instance, yes, you are looking at the same stack object.

Comment: Yes for sure you are

Comment: How could I implement the method to not do that? Whenever I have used this way of implementing it with other data-types, it has NOT created a pointer.

Comment: Stack<Tweet> tempTweets = new Stack<Tweet>();
  tempTweets = this.tweets; This gives the same thing. How do I copy tweets by value and not by reference?

Comment: @VegarAndreasBergum I think you want to clone the Stack. The simplest method would be to use the existing clone() method of the Stack. Although i'm not sure if that gives you a shallow copy (New Stack pointing to same objects as other list) or a deep dopy (new stack where all content was cloned as well). You should check out the JavaDoc of the clone method.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @VegarAndreasBergum `Stack<Tweet> tempTweets = (Stack<Tweet>) tweets.clone();`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS After further investigation I see that clone(): "Returns a clone of this vector. The copy will contain a reference to a clone of the internal data array, not a reference to the original internal data array of this Vector object.". From what I can see, it doesn't create a copy of the stack, but rather the contents of the stack. What I don't understand is why the get() method did not work? Doesn't a Stack inherit that from the Vector-object?

Comment: @Michael This! Just Stack<Tweet> instead of Integer. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @VegarAndreasBergum Because [Java.util.Stack is crap](https://keithwilliamstechblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/13/why-the-java-stack-class-is-bad/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case you're just looking at the same object. There is no copying happening here.

The easiest way to create a copy of a Stack is to clone it.

```
Stack<Tweet> tempTweets = (Stack<Tweet>) tweets.clone();
```

PS [Consider using `Deque` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack) because `Stack` is rubbish

Answer (score 0):

With code

```
 Stack<Tweet> tempTweets = tweets;
```

you create reference to the **tweets** object, so whatever you change with **tempTweets** e.g.

```
tempTweets.pop();
```

is also changed with **tweets**

If you want to make a copy of an object you can use [clone method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) from java Object. But it have to be implemented in **Stack**.

It's hard to say more without knowing objects you are using.

Comment: Yes, that is what I asked. How do I create a copy of tweets by value, and not reference?