# Practical usecase of class Stack's push method returning its argument

Tags: java, collections, stack, legacy-code

1) **class Stack:  public E push(E item)**

class Stack - its push method just returns its argument (unlike newer Deque, whose respective push method is now void):

```
public E push(E item)
```

Can you provide any useful real-life / production example of using this feature?

I understand that Stack is legacy, use Deque implementations instead.

But how this feature was used in legacy apps?   I guess it could be used for call chaining, but can't think of a practical example.

2) **Do you often have to work with Stack class in you everyday work?** Is it widely still widely used?  Or most legacy apps have already been refactored to use Deque?

3) **Is there any practical benefit (and is it worth it) to refactor Stack to Deque**, if I encounter Stack in any legacy app which I am actively developing (adding new features)? I understand that in new apps Deque is preferrable, but if I already have Stack in legacy app, from practical point of view are there cases when it is absolutely worth effort to refactor it to Deque?

4) Am I right, that if I need use stack datastructure in multithreaded access, I shall use  ConcurrentLinkedDeque (because I shall prefer Deque implementations over Stack class)? Or is there any practice to use Stack for multithreaded access nowadays? I think no, but I'd still like to ask gurus.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Yes. Consider this class:

```
class Foo
{
    public void activate() { }
}
```

Sometimes it's more concise to be able to write:

```
Stack<Foo> s = new Stack<>();
s.push(new Foo()).activate();
```

Rather than:

```
Stack<Foo> s = new Stack<>();
Foo f = new Foo();
f.activate();
s.push(f);
```

**2)** No, I've never used it or seen it used, at least in the last 5 years. I find that Stack's reputation precedes it. Most people know to avoid it, even if they're not clear why.

**3)** This is a duplicate of this question: [Why should I use Deque over Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack)

---

With regards to the question you deleted, related to the `search` method:

Your assumptions are incorrect. Stack extends Vector and so inherits all of Vector's public methods, one of which is [`elementAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#elementAt(int)). So you are able to use this index if you want to.