# How can I use stack in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, stack

How can I use Stack (from java) in Kotlin?

Or theres any other alternative?

- I'm trying to convert list to Stack

Comment: Don't use `Stack` anymore, it's very old java and relies on `Vector`. Instead use `Deque`, implemented by e.g. `ArrayDeque` or `LinkedList`

Comment: the stack implementation in java is quite bad either use the suggestion of @msrd0 or implement your own stack

Answer (score 66):

**Kotlin 1.3.70** introduced the [`kotlin.collections.ArrayDeque`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/) class, which functions as both a queue *and* a stack, like Java's [`java.util.Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (Deque meaning "double-ended queue"). It was created out of a necessity for a multiplatform `ArrayDeque` implementation.

```
val stack = ArrayDeque(listOf(1, 2, 3)) // stack: [1, 2, 3]
stack.addLast(0)                        // stack: [1, 2, 3, 0]         (push)
val value = stack.removeLast()          // value: 0, stack: [1, 2, 3]  (pop)
```

Note that if an `ArrayDeque` is empty when you call [`removeFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/remove-first.html) or [`removeLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/remove-last.html), it will throw a [`kotlin.NoSuchElementException`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-no-such-element-exception/index.html#kotlin.NoSuchElementException). If you don't want to check the size of your deque every time you need to access it, then you should use the [`removeFirstOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/remove-first-or-null.html) and [`removeLastOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/remove-last-or-null.html) functions.

---

**Optional Snippets**

`ArrayDeque` constructor function:

```
inline fun <T> arrayDequeOf(vararg elements: T) = ArrayDeque(elements.toList())
// ...
val stack = arrayDequeOf(1, 2, 3)
```

`Stack`-like `ArrayDeque` calls:

```
inline fun <T> ArrayDeque<T>.push(element: T) = addLast(element) // returns Unit

inline fun <T> ArrayDeque<T>.pop() = removeLastOrNull()          // returns T?
```

Comment: except it neither implements `Stack` nor `Queue` Interface unlike the Java Version...

Comment: yeah, that's why it doesn't provide those methods. Also implementing those interfaces would also mean that added methods would be inconsistent which IMHO is bad

Comment: @xeruf There are a few reasons why. Nowadays, Stack is discouraged in favour of Java's Deque, deques are double-sided while Queues are not (on a type level), Java's interfaces don't provide nullability information, reliance on JVM types makes the type less multiplatform, and probably a few others I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 45):

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque

var stack = ArrayDeque<Int>()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)
stack.push(4)
println(stack)           // --> [4, 3, 2, 1]
println(stack.isEmpty()) // --> false

println(stack.peek())    // --> 4
println(stack)           // --> [4, 3, 2, 1]

println(stack.pop())     // --> 4
println(stack)           // --> [3, 2, 1]

stack.push(9)
println(stack)           // --> [9, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This should be mentioned more in this thread - don't use Stack, instead use Deque.  For reasons why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack

Comment: Be careful because the iteration order of `ArrayDeque` when used as a stack is wrong.

Answer (score 25):

You can use following:

```
/**
 * Stack as type alias of Mutable List
 */
typealias Stack<T> = MutableList<T>

/**
 * Pushes item to [Stack]
 * @param item Item to be pushed
 */
inline fun <T> Stack<T>.push(item: T) = add(item)

/**
 * Pops (removes and return) last item from [Stack]
 * @return item Last item if [Stack] is not empty, null otherwise
 */
fun <T> Stack<T>.pop(): T? = if (isNotEmpty()) removeAt(lastIndex) else null

/**
 * Peeks (return) last item from [Stack]
 * @return item Last item if [Stack] is not empty, null otherwise
 */
fun <T> Stack<T>.peek(): T? = if (isNotEmpty()) this[lastIndex] else null
```

Comment: How would you initialize or construct such a stack? `val stack:Stack<Char> = MutableList(0){'.'}` or `val stack = MutableList(0){' '} as Stack<Char>`?

Comment: @dlamblin using an `ArrayDeque` as backing

Answer (score 16):

This is done in the same way as you would in Java, but with Kotlin syntax - notably different are the `val` keyword and lack of new keyword. For example:

```
import java.util.Stack
...
val someList = ArrayList()
...
val stack = Stack()
stack.addAll(someList)
```

Comment: As noted in the comment on the question, should use Deque instead of Stack.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack

Comment: Java collection in Kotlin?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes, Java collections work in Kotlin

Answer (score 12):

This is a few years old but I suspect there's room for a different approach. If you want to use a stack structure in Kotlin you certainly don't need to resort to Java. You could easily just create a new class with an internal Kotlin list and stack-like public functions, or use Kotlin's extension methods to give an existing Kotlin collection "stack-like" functionality, for example:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.push(item: T) = this.add(this.count(), item)
fun <T> MutableList<T>.pop(): T? = if(this.count() > 0) this.removeAt(this.count() - 1) else null
fun <T> MutableList<T>.peek(): T? = if(this.count() > 0) this[this.count() - 1] else null
fun <T> MutableList<T>.hasMore() = this.count() > 0
```

Then, optionally, you could use a typealias to make it more obvious what you're trying to do when using those functions:

```
typealias Stack = MutableList<MyClass>
```

Then create one and use it:

```
val myStack: Stack = mutableListOf()
myStack.push(MyClass())
myStack.pop()
```

etc

Answer (score 9):

I don't believe there's a specific separate implementation of Stack in Kotlin. You could definitely use the answer by Ed.

Alternatively, you could use a `mutableListOf<DataType>` construct, and then have custom methods that are on top of this.

It would be something like this :

```
var stackDemo = mutableListOf<String>()
```

To push an element

```
var count = stackDemo.count()
stackDemo.add(count,"One")
```

To pop an element

```
var count = stackDemo.count()
stackDemo.removeAt(count)
```

You can refer to this [Github link](https://github.com/gazolla/Kotlin-Algorithm/tree/master/Stack) for a model implementation

Comment: The use of 'count' here is unnecessary for adding elements, since it is the default location for single-parameter 'add'. Thus, 'stackDemo.add("One")' will suffice. Also, for removing elements, you should be using count()-1, not count(), or you will get exceptions thrown.

Comment: Is **mutableList** more memory-efficient than **stack**?

Answer (score 8):

you can define Stack like it.

```
val stack = Stack<YourStackType>()
```

notice that set the data type of your stack, for example stack of Int is like this:

```
val stack = Stack<Int>()
```

after that you can use push , pop , or other stack operations

example for Int stack :

```
a:Int = 10
stack.push(a)
a = stack.pop()
```

Comment: I get `Unresolved reference: Stack` when I try this.