# What is Kotlin for C++ push_back() and pop_back() on a string?

Tags: c++, kotlin

In C++ creating and manipulating a mutable stack of characters is rather simple. I use a built-in standard data type (std::string), use a push and pop fuctions that comes with it and can directly print the results. None of this requires creating additional classes or functions.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string path {};
    path.push_back('L');
    path.push_back('R');
    path.pop_back();
    std::cout << path;
}
```

Produces:

```
L
```

What is Kotlin for C++ `push_back()` and `pop_back()` as a stack of characters?

The question is not how can I implement these as member functions in Kotlin.

[C++ Shell code](http://cpp.sh/5syvdw)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use stack in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900048/how-can-i-use-stack-in-kotlin)

Comment: You can use [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) from java collections.

Answer (score 2):

`String`s are immutable, so you won't find an exact equivalent.
While [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is generally considered to be a decent string buffer type, `deleteCharAt` [copies the entire backing array](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/274a0bcce99d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#l1084).

You can use [`setLength`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength(int)) for this purpose. Note that, [as with `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit), this does not do anything more than modify the internal length of the string buffer:

```
val string = StringBuilder("Hello")
string.append(", world!")
string.setLength(string.length - 1)
```

Alternatively, take the more functional approach and work with immutable values:

```
var string = "Hello"
string += ", world!"
string = string.dropLast(1)
```

---

As already stated by other answerers/commenters, if what you *really* want is a stack or deque, see [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) and [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) (seeing as you did not mention `std::stack` or `std::deque` in your question, I do not believe this to be the case; not to mention that a stack of characters isn't inherently very useful.)

---

Taking OP's comment into account, this should be an idiomatic solution:

```
enum class Move {
    Left, Right, Forward
}

val moves = ArrayDeque<Move>()

// Push a move:
moves.push(Move.Left)

// Pop a move:
val lastMove = moves.pop()
```

---

See also [Why should I use Deque over Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack) for an explanation of Java's unfortunate history.

Comment: A maze like a mouse traverses with L(eft) R(ight) F(orward) steps can use a simple sequence of characters which when used as a stack can track the path.

Comment: @CWHolemanII ah. In that case I would use a deque of enums; though I would probably have done this in C++ as well. I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is what you mean, but Kotlin has a dropLast(param: number of characters to drop) function which returns a string without the number of characters you did want to remove. Link: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop-last.html

If you are looking for a stack data structure, you might take a look at the Stack and Deque data structures.
https://chercher.tech/kotlin/deque-kotlin, https://chercher.tech/kotlin/stack-kotlin