# Difference between Stack and synchronization decorator for ArrayDeque

Tags: java, stack, arraydeque, lifo

I want to have LIFO effect and I want it to be synchronized. Does anyone know which one of these two implementations I should use? Been googling for a while, still no good answer.

Bottom line: what are differences, why use one over another, why is it said to favor arrayDequeue?

Comment: Are you talking about `Stack` that is a child of `Vector`?

Comment: `Stack` is synchronized, `ArrayDeque` is not. If you want the latter in synchronized, use `LinkedBlockingDeque` or `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.

Comment: @PM77-1Yes I am :)

Comment: @akuzminykh Question is why favor one over another, differences etc.. I know the basic stuff, I don't understand the idea behind it all.

Comment: [Why should I use Deque over Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack)

Comment: @akuzminykh I already checked it, not so helpful..

Comment: [Why is Java Vector (and Stack) class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-and-stack-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I use Deque over Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack)

Answer (score 2):

From question:

> why is it said to favor arrayDequeue?

It is *not* said to favor [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) (a class).

It is said that you should favor [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (an interface) over [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) (a class), because you should [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384067/5221149), allowing you to substitute the *implementation* without otherwise changing your code.

The *"it is said ..."* is right there in the javadoc of `Stack`:

> A more **complete** and **consistent** set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

The Java Runtime Library comes with the following choices of implementation for a `Deque`:

- [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) - generally best choice for single-threaded use
- [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) - generally best choice for multi-threaded use
- [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) - if you need stack with size limit
- [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) - if stack can grow big, and you want to reclaim space as it shrinks

`LinkedBlockingDeque` uses locks, which is similar to using `synthronized`, but none of the others use `synchronized`. The way `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` is implemented to be thread-safe has proven to perform better than an implementation using `synchronized`. `ArrayDeque` is faster than `Stack` because it is not using `synchronized`, so is better for non-thread-safe code.

---

See also: [Why should I use Deque over Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12524826/5221149)
See also: [Why is Java Vector (and Stack) class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/5221149)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But forget about all of this, for a second. Decorator for ArrayDeque is absolutely same as Stack, is it? Meaning on performance looking. They both have synchronized each operation, did I get it?

Comment: @AnaMaria What decorator? There are no built-in decorators for `Deque`.

Comment: I could had swore there is collections.synchronizedQueue, because there is for Set,Map,List.. Why not queue as well? :/