# Empty Stack Exception

Tags: java, data-structures

```
class Solution{
static boolean ispar(String x){
    char [] arr = x.toCharArray();
    int length = arr.length;
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    
    boolean isBalanced = true;
    if(arr[0] == '}' || arr[0] == ')' || arr[0] == ']'){
         isBalanced = false;
    }
    else{   
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            char bracket = arr[i];
        
            if(bracket == '{' || bracket =='(' || bracket == '['){
                stack.push(bracket);
            }
            else if(!stack.empty() && 
                ((char) stack.peek() == '(' && (bracket == ')'))
                    || ((char) stack.peek() == '{' && bracket == '}')
                    || ((char) stack.peek() == '[' && bracket == ']')
                    ){
                stack.pop();
            }
            else{
            isBalanced = false;
            }
    }
    if(stack.empty()){
        isBalanced = true;            
   }
   else{
       isBalanced = false;
   }
 } 
 return isbalanced;
}
}
```

I am learning `Stack` data structure. And this is the first problem I am trying to solve but it is giving me this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.base/java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at Solution.ispar(File.java:57)
at Driverclass.main(File.java:23)
```

Comment: I would recommend debugging the program yourself, it will be a lot quicker and more useful. There's a great article about it here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The issue is with your `else if` block, `else if(!stack.empty() &&
                        ((char) stack.peek() == '(' && (bracket == ')')
                        || ((char) stack.peek() == '{' && bracket == '}')
                        || ((char) stack.peek() == '[' && bracket == ']')))` it need to change like this, and also `return isBalanced;` should be in last `return`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt to correct your code without changing your core attempt:

```
import java.util.Stack;

class Solution {
    public boolean isBalancedBrackets(String str) {
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        if (arr[0] == '}' || arr[0] == ')' || arr[0] == ']') {
            return false;
        } else {
            for (char bracket : arr) {
                if (bracket == '{' || bracket == '(' || bracket == '[') {
                    stack.push(bracket);
                } else if (!stack.empty() && 
                        (bracket == ')' && stack.peek() == '(' ||
                         bracket == '}' && stack.peek() == '{' ||
                         bracket == ']' && stack.peek() == '[')) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return stack.empty();
    }
}
```

**Changes:**

- Removed the redundant `isBalanced` variable, you can just return immediately when you detect a mismatch.
- For your else-if statement you need to group all the or conditions together, with one set of parentheses. This is the reason you are getting the `EmptyStackException`. Since you only want to check any of the three conditions if the stack is not empty.
- Renamed method.

Also, consider using a [Deque over a Stack in the future.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524826/why-should-i-use-deque-over-stack)

Comment: Actually there was enough pairs of parentheses in the nested else-if condition, but they were mis-placed. I think your answer will be more helpful if you explain why the whole bunch of pairs of comparisons needed to be bracketed together for the `!stack.empty()` part to work properly. :)

Comment: That's much more informative, IMO. Well done :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ommit letters in @Sash Sinha Solution you could add a new field:

```
private static Set<Character> bracketSet = Set.of('(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']');
```

and the method:

```
public static boolean ommitLetters(Character chr) {
    return bracketSet.contains(chr);
}
```

to implement it inside the loop:

```
...

        for (char bracket : arr)
            if (ommitLetters(bracket)) {
                if (bracket == '{' || bracket == '(' || bracket == '[') {
                    stack.push(bracket);
                } else if (!stack.empty() && (bracket == ')' && stack.peek() == '('
                        || bracket == '}' && stack.peek() == '{' || bracket == ']' && stack.peek() == '[')) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else
                continue;

 ...
```

Comment: +1 The logical extension of this would be to look into using a HashMap which would remove the requirement for the or statements completely.

Answer (score 0):

@ Sash Sinha - yes, using HashMap removes the requirement for the multi-or statements completely, ex:

```
public static <K, V> K getKeyFromMapByValue(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
    for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet())
        if (entry.getValue().equals(value))
            return entry.getKey();
    return null;
}

private static Set<Character> validParenthesisSet = Set.of('(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']');

public static boolean areParenthesisPaired(String expression) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    Map<Character, Character> parenthesisPairs = new HashMap<>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6725243592654448763L;
        {
            put('(', ')');
            put('{', '}');
            put('[', ']');
        }
    };

    for (Character actualParenthesis : expression.toCharArray()) {

        if (validParenthesisSet.contains(actualParenthesis))

            if (parenthesisPairs.containsValue(actualParenthesis)) { // must catch only closed
                Character oppositeParenthesis = getKeyFromMapByValue(parenthesisPairs, actualParenthesis);

                if (stack.size() == 0 || stack.peek() != oppositeParenthesis)
                    return false;

                stack.pop();

            } else
                stack.push(actualParenthesis);
    }

    if (stack.size() > 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```